# Tomcat cluster session replication for heterogenous different applications

Tags: session, tomcat, authentication, replication, load-balancing

SO I might know the answer to this question in my head but I don't seem to pinpoint it and I get even more confused when I think about it.

I'm doing some research into web app architectures for high scalability/maintainability (and all the other cool to-have's). I am trying to study one architecture where we have a cluster with 3-nodes.

node 1.[HIGH SECURITY , MEDIUM RAM, LOW DISK SPACE] Has administration apps like configurationService, authenticationService (I call it admin0)

node 2. [MEDIUM SECURITY, LOW RAM, HIGH DISK SPACE] Has content-oriented apps e.g. Media service(like file hosting), Profiles, etc etc. Just storage oriented node, I call it misc0.

node 3. [LOW SECURITY, HIGH RAM, MEDIUM DISK SPACE] Has business apps i.e. core apps for the web app.

So this separates concerns and if we want to scale, we can scale each node separately. Also, I think node 3 will be the one with the maximum load.

Now, the problem is, if a user gets authenticated on node1(admin0)/authenticationService, I want his session to be activated for all apps in the cluster so they don't have to query authenticationService anymore, they should just look up their local HttpSession.

Now, Tomcat clustering with Delta (or Backup) manager provides this functionality but they only share sessions with nodes where this app is installed. Though delta manager will share session even if app is not installed on the peers, I don't know how to use that session though? I know you can set the cookie's path to "/", is that my solution ?

Am I making a architectural mistake somewhere? I mean am I better off with a single sign-on solution or ?

Answer (score 0):

Even with single sign-on (SSO), each web application gets a different `HttpSession`, so you can't just "look up their local HttpSession". If you use Tomcat's SSO, it isn't clear to me whether or not that works across a cluster.

If you set the cookie path to "/", you'll only cause confusion because you need to have different cookies for different session ids for different applications.

Comment: Very true, but "business apps" i.e. node3 (core0) has only a single WAR so sessions should be shared automatically.

Comment: That's fine, but I'm not sure if SSO works across a cluster. You'd have to check that. If it does work, then you're all set.